# Is it possible to add both Angularjs 1.6.x and angular 2 statements in a single .js file?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have been trying to come up with some ideas of getting angularjs and angular 2 versions to combine in a single JS file.

Is it possible , if so kindly provide me a solution to execute that ?

Comment: Angularjs and Angular2 is entirely different . So you can't use it together.

Comment: @user7333505 You are completely and totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are already have an AngularJS codebase, you can use ng-forward / ng-upgrade to start writing Angular like code which will make upgrading a lot easier.

The github is here https://github.com/ngUpgraders/ng-forward

If you are starting a new project definitely just use Angular and skip AngularJS entirely.